# In Linux shell, how to use regex to filter output of other command.

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

In Linux shell, how to use regex to filter output of other command.
like in cisco devices we use sh ver | b interface, which will dispaly info about int only.
my requirement is filter output of below command to display from "Dogstatsd (v 5.12.0)" and status date & time.

So that i can use this o/p with certain criteria to write a script to auto restart the agent.

## root@adcd:~# service datadog-agent info -v

## Collector (v 5.12.0)

Status date: 2017-05-30 08:20:13 (17s ago)
  Pid: 7864
  Platform: Linux-3.11.0-24-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-13.10-saucy
  Python Version: 2.7.13, 64bit
  Logs: , /var/log/datadog/collector.log, syslog:/dev/log

Clocks
  ======

NTP offset: 0.018 s
    System UTC time: 2017-05-30 06:20:31.535928

Paths
  =====

conf.d: /etc/dd-agent/conf.d
    checks.d: /opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks.d

Hostnames
  =========

socket-hostname: adcd
    hostname: adcd
    socket-fqdn: adcd

Checks
  ======

apache (5.0)
    ---------------
      - instance #0 [OK]
      - Collected 12 metrics, 0 events & 1 service check

network (5.0)
    ----------------
      - instance #0 [OK]
      - Collected 16 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks

directory (5.0)
    ------------------
      - instance #0 [OK]
      - Collected 17 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks

ntp (5.0)
    ------------
      - Collected 0 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks

disk (5.0)
    -------------
      - instance #0 [OK]
      - Collected 24 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks

Emitters
  ========

- http_emitter [OK]

====================

## Dogstatsd (v 5.12.0)

Status date: 2017-05-30 08:20:24 (7s ago)
  Pid: 7859
  Platform: Linux-3.11.0-24-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-13.10-saucy
  Python Version: 2.7.13, 64bit
  Logs: , /var/log/datadog/dogstatsd.log, syslog:/dev/log

Flush count: 583466
  Packet Count: 333155
  Packets per second: 0.0
  Metric count: 1
  Event count: 0
  Service check count: 1

====================

## Forwarder (v 5.12.0)

Status date: 2017-05-30 08:20:29 (2s ago)
  Pid: 8868
  Platform: Linux-3.11.0-24-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-13.10-saucy
  Python Version: 2.7.13, 64bit
  Logs: , /var/log/datadog/forwarder.log, syslog:/dev/log

Queue Size: 422 bytes
  Queue Length: 1
  Flush Count: 1102592
  Transactions received: 879956
  Transactions flushed: 879955
  Transactions rejected: 0
  API Key Status: API Key is valid

======================

## Trace Agent (v 5.12.0)

Not running (port 8126)

root@adcd:~#

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the program, but I've had to solve a problem like this before.  I'm making the assumption that you're always going to start the output you want with a line 'Dogstatsd', and always end with several equals signs.  Based on that, you could script out your output like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

service datadog-agent info -v > /tmp/DogstatsDump.txt

LinesTotal=$(cat /tmp/DogstatsDump.txt | wc -l)

StartOfOutput=$(grep /tmp/DogstatsDump.txt -ne '^Dogstatsd (v' | cut -d':' -f 1)

LengthOfOutput=$(tail -n $(echo "$LinesTotal - $StartOfOutput + 1" | bc)/tmp/DogstatsDump.txt  | grep -ne '^==========' | head -n 1 | cut -d':' -f 1 )

tail -n $(echo "$LinesTotal - $StartOfOutput + 1" | bc) /tmp/DogstatsDump.txt  | head -n $(echo "$LengthOfOutput + 1" | bc)

rm /tmp/DogstatsDump.txt
```

We get the values defining the length of the file, the length until we hit the first line you want, the length where the output ends, and trim accordingly.